# expand navigation bar horizontally onmouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple navigation bar however i want to improve the navigation bar to when i click on one button the navigation bar expand horizontally through the button from both sides. So i will have one button in the center and on click the menu will form from left and right.

**HTML**

```
<nav align="middle">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/video-1.png" class="video" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/news-1.png" class="news" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/logo-4.png" class="home" style="width:80px;height:80px;"onmouseover="this.src='images/logo-4-hover.png';"
 onmouseout="this.src='images/logo-4.png';"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/games-1.png" class="games" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="images/music-1.png" class="music" style="width:100px;height:50px;"></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
li {

display: inline;
margin-right: .75em;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

html,body {
height:100%;  /* new */
}


ul {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 5px solid black;
border-width: 5px 0;  
background-color: #515151;
}
```

Comment: i have looked through different sources but they are all drop down. none of them are horizontal animating the navbar

Comment: yes, there is no need to reinvent the wheel in programming. but if you cannot find a ready solution anywhere, usually its time to try writing it yourself. have you tried anything yet, or just waiting for someone to give you the solution on a silver plate?

Comment: no i have not tried it yet, i am yet to find tutorials on it

Comment: I didn't quite understand your desired result. You want a nav bar that you click on a button and it hides the other buttons on it's sides?

Comment: I know i can set up a jquery for when i click on a button the button go from hiden to clear and vice versa. but i want to make look better so instead of the navigation buttons show straight away they slide into position

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Animate.css. Link here: http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

One of the options is the "FadeInLeft". You can use those two (left and right) to the menus you want, and you will barely need any JavaScript code.

You can apply them to the left buttons, and the right ones, and make them go on click once you click the inner button.

Good luck!

Comment: that what i was thinking aswell i wasnt sure if it would work. I will try it out.